# Dynamics AX dialog multiselect

Tags: dialog, axapta, multi-select

Is it possible to add a control in a dialog that allows multiple selections using a dropdown?

For example, I want to give the user a dropdown to select multiple companies. Depending upon the companies selected, I want to do some processing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on form `tutorial_LookupMultiSelectGrid` which has an implementation of that. It uses the class `SysLookupMultiSelectCtrl` which has no help text, but has [a nice write here](http://dynamicsaxgyan.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/syslookupmultiselectctrl-in-dynamics-ax-6-0-ax-2012-x/).

Also you can do some primitive workaround using `replaceOnLookup`:

```
ClassDeclation X extends Runbase
{
    str companies;
    DialogField dlgCompanies;
}
public Object dialog()
{
    DialogRunbase dialog = super();
    FormStringControl fsc;  
    dlgCompanies = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(CompanyId), companies);
    fsc = dlgCompanies.control();
    fsc.replaceOnLookup(false);
    return dialog;
}
```

Then agree with the users that they must enter commas between the companies. Then convert the string to container using `str2con(companies)` and iterate over that.

Instead of the `CompanyId` EDT, consider making your own with a longer size!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version you are using.

To do this I would create a class exteding RunBase/RunBaseBatch (RubBase classes are not recommended in AX 2012 anymore, but still working) and replace the standard dialog with a custome form created in AOT
On a form you can place a list control which allows multiselect. Then you have to write some code to pass user selection back to the runbase class.

If it not enough for you let me know, tomorrow I can lookup a similar solution in standard AX.

Regards,
Sebastian